# How can i solve aw_blog error

Tags: magento-1.9, category

Am hosted my local host developed site, when i try to access categories i cant be accessed, its not be a clickable link,  but my localhost am accessed my all categories.

**

- Live Site :

**

[image]

**

- Localhost Site :

**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a aw_blog error. please check is there any other jquery is loaded. means diff-2 version of jquery in admin loaded at one time. or also please check the is there any module exist which overwrite the functionality of category

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Magento `.htaccess` file on your root and server `rewrites` are enabled.

Comment: yes, my rewrites enabled, any other options >>